# Extracting private key in Java from a [Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Local Computer] key store

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, x509certificate, keystore

I would appreciate your assistance with a problem am facing while extracting a private key from a Windows **[Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Local Computer]** key store. I have this piece of code:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
keyStore.load(null, null);
String alias = "MyAlias";

// Extract key associated with the specified alias
Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);

if (key instanceOf PrivateKey) {
    // Do stuff ...
}
```

Here is the problem. The key gets extracted successfully when I am remotely logged in to production PC as <Computer IP>\Administrator BUT fails (i.e. `Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, null);` returns **null**) when am remotely logged in as <Domain>\MyUserName. However, the certificate gets extracted successfully in both cases.

It gets even more interesting. On my development PC, the key is extracted successfully BOTH when am logged in as local Administrator as well as when am logged in as <Domain>\MyUserName.

On both production PC and development PC, certificate was installed with Administrator logged in. <Domain>\MyUserName is in the Administrators group on both development PC and production server. When the certificates were being installed, *Enable strong private key protection.* option was not checked.

Comment: Why would there *be* a private key in such a keystore? As its name suggests, it is there to contain certificates of trusted CAs, not private keys.

Comment: @EJP Which keystore - on Windows - should I use to store a private key entry to be applied by a utility for encryption given that different users will log in to the PC and use the utility?

Comment: Just wondering: What is the private key's purpose?

Comment: if it is user certificate, then each user should have its own certificate (not shared). These certificates must be installed in Current User\Personal (CurrentUser\My).